# Setting path for Start_IPython_Kernel.py in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, ipython, zeromq, anaconda, spyder

I have just installed ***Anaconda3-2.3.0-Windows-x86_64***. Previously I was using 
***Anaconda-2.0.1-Windows-x86*** (32-bit). I have both **Anaconda** and **Anaconda3** folders (this is a machine at work, so I need to keep both for backward compatibility).

Then, I set in Spyder's Console Preferences to have it look for ***python.exe*** and ***scientfic_startup.py*** in the ***Ananconda3*** folder, instead of ***Anaconda***.

Then, when I start Spyder, it gets the following error related to ***zmq***. It seems to keep looking for files in the ***old Anaconda*** folder, and not in the ***new Anaconda3*** folder. Will the problem go away if it looks for things in Anaconda3, and, if so, how can I get Spyder to look for it in Anaconda3?

```
 "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\start_ipython_kernel.py", line 167, in from IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp import IPKernelApp

 File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\IPytho \kernel\__init__.py", line 4, in from . import zmq

 File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\IPytho \kernel\zmq\__init__.py", line 8, in  check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.kernel.zmq')

 File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site‑packages\IPytho\utils\zmqrelated.py", line 10, in check_for_zmq import zmq

 File "C:\Users\O629626\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anacond\lib\site‑packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 42, in _libsodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled_sodium[0])

 File "C:\Users\O629626\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 429, in LoadLibrary

 return self._dlltype(name)

 File "C:\Users\O629626\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ctype \__init__.py", line 351, in __init__

 self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

 OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 1):

Opening the default Spyder associated with the specific Anaconda resolved the issue.